# google analytics pixel is firing but no results

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking my application with Google Analytics [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), I had implemented a code into my web site, and into my desktop application using POST web requests.
Everything works fine in last Wednesday(20.11.13), and I could see the results in the real-time report. But today(24.11.13) the real time reportstopped showing results.
I had tryed to debug it with fiddler, and the pixels seems to fire correctly, so my questions are:

1. how do I check that Google Analytics actually accepted the tracking request? does 200 header response is good enough?
2. Do you know if Google had changed their API?
3. Do you know if they have problems with their real time report? (my other real time reportis still working so I don't think this is the reason)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, If anyone encountered this weird issue, the solution is wierder.
My production GA works fine but all the test one stopped working, the solution was toopen a new GA account and point my GA pixels to this account.

I believe they have a glitch or they blocked my test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Omnibug for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibug/) or [GA Debug for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). They will tell you weather your measuring tags fired successfully or if there was an issue.

I am attaching a screenshot of Omnibug -- it lists all the tags fired on any given page:

[image]